# VS Code cannot find git bash shell

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've reinstalled git on another drive today, and I cannot seem to make vs code figure out where git is.

I've as configuration in settings.json

```dart
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Git Bash": {
      "path": "D:\\Programs\\Git\\bin",
      "source": "Git Bash",
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
```

but when vs code starts the error message is

`cannot find top level C:\Programs file\git\bin`

and

`The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '--login'" terminated with exit code: 1.`

Which is the wrong path.

Yes the path is the correct one in environment variables:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you mean `"git.path"`. The `"path"` directive in terminal profiles is meant for a shell. Perhaps we need some context.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález this is the terminal of vs code "Git Bash" throwing the error

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález edited the title, git side bar works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

removing source and icon worked:

```
"Git Bash": {
  "path": "D:\\Programs\\Git\\bin",
  "source": "Git Bash",
  "icon": "terminal-bash"
},
```

to

```
"GitBash": {
  "path": "D:\\Programs\\Git\\bin"
},
```